# How can I edit my dates with a DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker, gmt

I am using two different Datepickers to select the start and end date.For the day and month and year I choose, I want to get the moment that day began.For example 18 September 2018, 18 September 2018 and the hour 00.00. I would like to disable `GMT` differences if possible. With `datepicker`, I share the logs for the dates I selected.

```
D/START DATE: Sun Sep 23 18:23:51 GMT+03:00 2018
D/END DATE: Sun Sep 30 18:23:51 GMT+03:00 2018
```

The logs I want are as follows:

```
D/START DATE: Sun Sep 23 00:00:00 2018
D/END DATE: Sun Sep 30 23:59:59 2018
```

This means that any time within the start day must be valid and any time until the end date ends for the end date. How do I make that happen?

Comment: Consider java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It’s generally much nicer to work with and in particular better suited for a filtering task like yours. If you are coding for less that new Android, add the ThreeTenABP library to your project to use java.time, see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Use half-open intervals: When the user picks Sep 23 and 30, include times that are on or after Sep 23 at 00:00 and **strictly before Oct 1 at 00:00**. Do keep the GMT offset, or you won’t be able to tell whether a time is before or after these limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your calendar value like this:

```
yourTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
yourTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
yourTime.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
```

Or

```
yourTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
yourTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
yourTime.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);
```

Where yourTime is Calendar instance. Hope it would help.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

```
String dateOfDay = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy").format(new Date());
String time = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss", new Date().getTime()).toString();
```

That could be the answer you're looking for. You can also find shortcuts in the top link.